# How do I find the latest migration created w/ flask-migrate?

Tags: python, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

My flask application now has 20+ migrations built with `flask-migrate` and they all have hashed file names like: `389d9662fec7_.py`

I want to double check the settings on the latest migration that I ran, but don't want to open every file to look for the correct one. I could create a new dummy migration and look at what it references as the `down_revision` but that seems clunky.

I'm using `flask-script`, `flask-migrate`, and `flask-sqlalchemy`

My question is: **How can I quickly find the latest migration that I created?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./manage.py db history -r current:` will show the migrations in the order they will be applied. `-r current:` shows only the migrations since the currently applied one.

`./manage.py db heads` will show the most recent migration for each branch (typically there's only one branch). `./manage.py db upgrade` would apply all migrations to get to the head.

Use the `-v` flag to get verbose output, including the full path to the migration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check in your database and the current version should be displayed in a table called alembic_version.